# How to make querying dynamodb xray as a subsegment of a customised segment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-xray

I have a lambda function which queries dynamodb multiple times. I'd like to use `xray` to get the performance about the query.

I created the lambda in nodejs:

```
this.documentClient = new DocumentClient({
      service: new DynamoDB(),
    });
AWSXray.captureAWSClient((this.documentClient as any).service);
```

when querying dynamodb, I am using the code:

```
const segment = AWSXRay.getSegment();
const subsegment = segment.addNewSubsegment('query dynamodb');
await this.documentClient.query(...).promise();
await this.documentClient.query(...).promise();
await this.documentClient.query(...).promise();
...
subsegment.close();
```

I am able to see the trace data:

[image]

But the problem is the `query dynamodb` segment is not the parent of other dynamodb query subsegments. How can I wrap all dynamodb query inside my customised segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the `query dynamodb` subsegment is not being set in the context for the `DynamoDB` subsegments to be parented. As a result, the parent for all the subsegments is the Lambda FacadeSegment. You can try using the [Manual Mode](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#automatic-and-manual-mode) to manually pass around the `subsegment` to the DDB calls. Refer to the [example](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#capture-outgoing-aws-requests-on-a-single-client-1) for details.